# Invoking application scoped bean jsf

Tags: java, jsf

In my applicatoin I have a application scoped bean, which I call it like this:
`FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getApplicationMap().get("name");`

What is the best way to initialize it?

The way I do till now it to call one of its properies in the first jsf page, for no need - just initializing the bean.

The page looks like this:

```
 <h:inputHidden id="inovkeBean" value="#{myBean.nothing}"/>
```

And the bean:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyBean {

String nothing;

public String getNothing() {
    return nothing;
}
```

}

It works fine, just i'm asking: can anybody tell me a nicer way to initialize the bean?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using JSF2.0 mark it as `eager="true"` so it will get constructed when JSF context will get initilized

```
@ManagedBean(eager=true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class SomePojo { }
```

Comment: How can you define this property in `faces-config.xml` file